# how to disable add product button in opportunity when i select stage as prospect

Tags: opportunity, product

How to disable add product button in opportunity when i select stage as prospect

I want to disable add product button in related list of opportunity when i select stage as prospect. and i want to enable that button when my stage is ordered. please help me

Comment: you can override the add product button and show the alert message. based on your condition

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new custom button from Setup-> Opportunity product-> Button and Links
2. Add following code in that

   ```
   if({!ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.StageName, 'Prospecting')})
   {
       alert('You can not add product');
   }
   else
   {
     window.location.href='/p/opp/SelectSearch?addTo={!Opportunity.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}'
   }
   ```

[image]

3.Add button to Opporutnity page layout in related list of product.

[image]